# Finding out the last columns format problem

Tags: excel, vba

Can you please help me edit this code to make it possible. I think it's format problem. But i don't know how to solve it. 
My code is to find out how many columns we have.

```
Range("m4").Value = Range(""A" & Columns.Count, 1").End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to address cells.
A cell is defined by its coordinates, row and column numbers, like `Cells([Row], [Column])`. A cell is a member of the `Cells` collection which are all the cells within a range. Plain `Cells` refers to the collection of all the cells in the `ActiveSheet`. Therefore `Cells(4, 1)` defines `Range("A4")`. A cell is a range object.

`Cells(2, Columns.Count)` specifies the last cell in row 2.
`Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)` instructs to move to the left from that last cell until a used cell is detected. The return is a range object, obviously, a single cell.

That range object has `Column` and `Row` properties as well as a `Value` property. Therefore you can ask for

```
Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Value
' or
Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Row
' or
Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
' or
Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address
```

You can also use the cell as the end point of a range.

```
Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
```

Comment: I think I confused the range and cell. Thanks for clarification.